# Grabbing a substring from text with bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am tring to extract a substring from some text and I am struggling to find the correct sed or regex that will do it for me.

My input text could be one of the following

```
feature/XXX-9999-SomeOtherText
develop
feature/XXX-99999-SomeMoreText
bugfix/XXX-9999
feature/XXXX-9999
XXX-9999
```

and I want to pull out just the XXX-9999, but there can be any number of Xs and 9s. where there are no Xs or 9s (as per the second example) I would like to return an empty value.

I have tried several ways using sed and the closest I got was

```
echo "feature/XXX-9999-SomeOtherText" | sed 's/.*\([[:alpha:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{4\}\).*/\1/'
```

which works if there are 3 Xs and 4 9s but anything else gives the full input string.

Comment: Post your expected output as `where there are no Xs or 9s (as per the second example) I would like to return an empty value` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` and its `-o` option:

```
grep -o 'X\+-9\+'
```

---

If you want non-matching lines to result in empty lines you can add `|| echo ''`.

Comment: My version of grep (on Windows) does not like the -o option, version 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's#\(^\|.*/\)\([a-Z0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\).*#\2#g; /[a-zA-Z0-9]\+-[0-9]\+/!s#.*##g' yourfile
```

Comment: I get the error

    **sed: -e expression #1, char 42: Invalid range end**

When I try that. I am using sed 4.2.1 on a windows machine, provided by git

Comment: @Klunk, Try this: `sed -r 's#(^|.*/)([a-Z0-9]+\-[0-9]+).*#\2#g; /[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-[0-9]+/!s#.*##g'` **OR** `sed 's#\(^\|.*/\)\([a-Z0-9]\+\-[0-9]\+\).*#\2#g; /[a-zA-Z0-9]\+\-[0-9]\+/!s#.*##g'`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "feature/XXX-9999-SomeOtherText\nnoX nor 9" | sed 's/.*\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}-[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/
t
s/.*//'
```

you use a count that is fixed in your test `{3}` so any number of X equal or greater succeed but not less. Change it to a minimum `{1,}`  (equivalent to the `+` for GNU sed).
I also add the non container to empty line (not removing the line), if not needed, remove fom `t` until last `/`

Answer (score 0):

Run on your posted sample input file:

```
$ sed -r -n 's/[^X]*(X+-9+).*/\1/p' file
XXX-9999
XXX-99999
XXX-9999
XXXX-9999
XXX-9999

$ sed -r -n 's/[^X]*(X+-9+)?.*/\1/p' file
XXX-9999

XXX-99999
XXX-9999
XXXX-9999
XXX-9999
```

The above IMHO shows a couple of the most likely interpretations of `where there are no Xs or 9s (as per the second example) I would like to return an empty value`.

If your sed doesn't support `-r` then this would work with any sed:

```
sed -n 's/[^X]*\(XX*-99*\).*/\1/p' file
sed -n 's/[^X]*\(XX*-99*\)*.*/\1/p' file
```